# Нахождение обьекта в WeakMap или WeakSet

Tags: javascript

```
const collection = new WeakSet()
collection.add({age: 100})
collection.has({age: 100}) // false
```

Почему false? И как мне найти объект, если их будет много? Причем в Set() и Map() тоже самое. Если добавлять вместо объектов примитивные типы  - то true

Comment: потому что проверка по ссылке, а вы каждый раз новый объект передаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка происходит по ссылке не для примитивов.
 А вы каждый раз передаете новый объект ( ссылку ), поэтому у вас `false`. Если делать все через переменную, то все ок

```js
const collection = new WeakSet()
const data = {age: 100}
collection.add(data)
console.log(collection.has(data)) // true
```

Comment: А примитивы в Weak* и нельзя положить